# How to "actually" configure PHP APC?

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, apc

I have VPS and it runs a wp blog plus a simple one page site. I am trying to use APC for blog. Before installing APC VPS was sending me alerts saying WP index.php was eating up everything. Now after installing APC these alerts have stopped. But when I check the result using apc.php I don't see any file in system cache.

Here is the PHP Info:

```
APC Support enabled
Version     3.1.9
APC Debugging   Disabled
MMAP Support    Enabled
MMAP File Mask  no value
Locking type    pthread mutex Locks
Serialization Support   php
Revision    $Revision: 308812 $
Build Date  Dec 13 2011 10:12:43

Directive   Local Value Master Value
apc.cache_by_default    On  On
apc.canonicalize    On  On
apc.coredump_unmap  Off Off
apc.enable_cli  Off Off
apc.enabled On  On
apc.file_md5    Off Off
apc.file_update_protection  2   2
apc.filters apc\.php$   apc\.php$
apc.gc_ttl  3600    3600
apc.include_once_override   Off Off
apc.lazy_classes    Off Off
apc.lazy_functions  Off Off
apc.max_file_size   1M  1M
apc.mmap_file_mask  no value    no value
apc.num_files_hint  1000    1000
apc.preload_path    no value    no value
apc.report_autofilter   Off Off
apc.rfc1867 Off Off
apc.rfc1867_freq    0   0
apc.rfc1867_name    APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
apc.rfc1867_prefix  upload_ upload_
apc.rfc1867_ttl 3600    3600
apc.serializer  default default
apc.shm_segments    1   1
apc.shm_size    30  30
apc.slam_defense    Off Off
apc.stat    On  On
apc.stat_ctime  Off Off
apc.ttl 0   0
apc.use_request_time    On  On
apc.user_entries_hint   100 100
apc.user_ttl    0   0
apc.write_lock  On  On
```

I am confused as what is actually going on. I have tried to read all possible sources but I am getting confused. How do I make only cache WP index.php and not others? It's a simple mod_php set up not the FastCGI setup.

Comment: Why don't you want to cache everything? APC is a greast opcode cache.

Comment: Why do you want to cache only index.php? APC is bytecode cache, not full page cache, so I think you can cache all PHP files without any problems.

Comment: @EmilVikström I would love to but I am unable to understand how can I enable APC to cache everything? AFAIK, I have just excluded apc.php from caching and APC must cache everything but I dont see any entry in "System Cache Entries", what do I need to do now?

Comment: @VladimirKadalashvili, read my above comment^

Answer (score 2):

Like the comment says, I have no idea why you wouldn't want everything cached.

However, there seems to be a way to do what you want, according to the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.filters). You can use a regex in the apc.filters property to exclude everything except the index.php file. I'm not a regex expert, but something along the lines of this in your apc.ini should work;

> apc.filter=!index\.php

Comment: Chris, I would be happy to do that but its not working as intended, I have excluded the apc.php by `apc.filter="index\.php$"` and this part works but I dont see any entry in "System Cache Entries"